# Why is my component returning before executing useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

My code is going to be quite explanatory in itself.

```
export default function ViewCustomer() {
    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState();
    const {id} = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        CustomerService.getCustomerById(id).then(res => {
            setCustomer(res.data);
        });
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div>
           {customer.first_name}
        </div>
    );
}
```

My code gives **customer is undefined** error. This is happening because useEffect hook is not executing before return is being executed. How and why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: The useEffect hook runs after the first render, you need to do a null check on customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *by design* and you shouldn't try to fix it. Assume that `customer` will be undefined for the first render, and handle that case. It will have the correct value for the second render.

You can for example render a 'loading spinner', or nothing at all but React is asking you to make an explicit decision on what to do while your data is still being loaded.